# How do I get the nodes hidden by the cutting plane?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

How can I get the nodes hidden in the cutting plane, like with `VisibilityManager.getHiddenNodes()`?

Answer (score 0):

The viewer itself doesn't provide any helper method for that. The `getHiddenNodes` method only tells you which nodes have been "marked as hidden".

You should however be able to detect which nodes have been "cut off" completely by the section plane using a little bit of math. Just get the bounding box of each geometry fragment, and test the 8 corner points of the bounding box against the section plane. If all 8 points are "behind the plane", you can say that the entire fragment is cut off.